# How can I find the minimum value in a map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, stdmap, minimum

I have a `map` and I want to find the minimum value (right-hand side) in the map. Here is how I did it:

```
bool compare(std::pair<std::string ,int> i, pair<std::string, int> j) {
  return i.second < j.second;
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
std::map<std::string, int> mymap;

mymap["key1"] = 50;
mymap["key2"] = 20;
mymap["key3"] = 100;

std::pair<char, int> min = *min_element(mymap.begin(), mymap.end(), compare); 
std::cout << "min " << min.second<< " " << std::endl;
```

The code above works fine and I'm able to get the minimum value. However, when I put this code inside my class as follows, it doesn't seem to work:

```
int MyClass::getMin(std::map<std::string, int> mymap) {
  std::pair<std::string, int> min = *min_element(mymap.begin(), mymap.end(), 
                                                 (*this).compare);
                                                 // Error probably due to "this".
  return min.second; 
}

bool MyClass::compare(
    std::pair<std::string, int> i, std::pair<std::string, int> j) { 
  return i.second < j.second; 
}
```

How can I make the code work with my class? Also, is there a better solution which doesn't require writing the additional `compare` function?

Comment: THe getMin function should be passing the argument by const reference, and not by value. Also, you will have a problem when the map has no elements at all, so consider not dereferecing the iterator before makig sure end() was not returned.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element has linear time. So it's better to implement its own associative container R/B, AVL, 2-3 and support minimum operation for it if standard library does not support it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have a few options. The "best" way to do this is with a *functor*, this is guaranteed to be the fastest to call:

```
typedef std::pair<std::string, int> MyPairType;
struct CompareSecond
{
    bool operator()(const MyPairType& left, const MyPairType& right) const
    {
        return left.second < right.second;
    }
};



int MyClass::getMin(std::map<std::string, int> mymap) 
{
  std::pair<std::string, int> min 
      = *min_element(mymap.begin(), mymap.end(), CompareSecond());
  return min.second; 
}
```

(You can also nest the `CompareSecond` class inside `MyClass`.

With the code you have now, you can easily modify it to work, however. Just make the function `static` and use the correct syntax:

```
static bool 
MyClass::compare(std::pair<std::string, int> i, std::pair<std::string, int> j) 
{ 
  return i.second < j.second; 
}

int MyClass::getMin(std::map<std::string, int> mymap) 
{
  std::pair<std::string, int> min = *min_element(mymap.begin(), mymap.end(), 
                                                 &MyClass::compare);
  return min.second; 
}
```

Comment: I hit the format button for you. You need to specify the template arguments to the functor or pass an unused argument to a factory. Or template the `operator()` instead of the whole class… that's the best way, yeah :vP .

Comment: I agree, `operator()` should be templated in best practice. However, I think the code should illustrate the point. 

What do you mean by "specify the template arguments"? Do you mean derive from `binary_function`? I don't believe that is required for `min_element`...

Answer (score 19):

In C++11 you can do this:

```
auto it = min_element(pairs.begin(), pairs.end(),
                      [](decltype(pairs)::value_type& l, decltype(pairs)::value_type& r) -> bool { return l.second < r.second; });
```

Or put it in a nice function like this (note I'm not a template guru; this is probably wrong in many ways):

```
template<typename T>
typename T::iterator min_map_element(T& m)
{
    return min_element(m.begin(), m.end(), [](typename T::value_type& l, typename T::value_type& r) -> bool { return l.second < r.second; });
}
```

---

With C++14, it further simplifies to:

```
min_element(pairs.begin(), pairs.end(),
            [](const auto& l, const auto& r) { return l.second < r.second; });
```

Comment: I made my lambda more succient by just using `auto` for the parameter types `l` and `r`.  That may require C++14, however.

Answer (score 3):

### C++14

As mentioned in [Jonathan Geisler's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659248/finding-minimum-value-in-a-map#comment72562684_26843031) comment on [Timmmm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26843031/2675154), [C++14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14) allows [lambda function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) parameters to be declared with the `auto` type specifier. As a result, you can shorten Timmmm's lambda-based [`min_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) line (and improve its readability) as follows:

```
auto it = std::min_element(std::begin(mymap), std::end(mymap),
                           [](const auto& l, const auto& r) { return l.second < r.second; });
```

Note 1: If you put this line into your `MyClass::getMin()` function, you have to return `it->second`. However, to account for an empty map, you should adapt the `return` line as follows (or similar):

```
return it == mymap.end() ? -1 : it->second;
```

Note 2: As also mentioned by [Lance Diduck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659248/how-can-i-find-the-minimum-value-in-a-map/56479262#comment2676405_2659248), you should be passing the map by `const` reference to your `getMin()` function. The way you did it, you are creating an unnecessary copy of the whole map.

[Code on Ideone](https://ideone.com/CZ8Se8)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that this:

```
bool MyClass::compare
```

Requires an instance of the class to be called on. That is, you can't just call `MyClass::compare`, but you need `someInstance.compare`. However, `min_element` needs the former.

The easy solution is to make it `static`:

```
static bool MyClass::compare

// ...

min_element(mymap.begin(), mymap.end(), &MyClass::compare);
```

This no longer requires an instance to be called on, and your code will be fine. You can make it more general with a functor, though:

```
struct compare2nd
{
    template <typename T>
    bool operator()(const T& pLhs, const T& pRhs)
    {
        return pLhs.second < pRhs.second;
    }
};

min_element(mymap.begin(), mymap.end(), compare2nd());
```

All this does is grab the second from each pair and grab them, works with any pair. It could be made for general, but that's a bit too much.

If you need to look up by value enough, I recommend you use Boost's [Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html). It's a bi-directional map, so both the key and value can be used to lookup. You would simply get the front of the value-key map.

Lastly, you can always just keep track of the minimum element going into your map. Every time you insert a new value, check if it's lower than your current value (and that should be probably be a pointer to a map pair, start it as null), and if it's lower, point to the new lowest. Requesting the lowest becomes as simple as dereferencing a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

I actually have another question: if you need to regularly obtain the minimum of the right-hand side values are you sure than a `map` is the best structure ?

I would suggest using `Boost.MultiIndex` in general for these problems of multiple ways of indexing the same set of objects... but if you only need this "reverse-mapping" bit `Boost.Bimap` might prove easier.

This way you won't have a linear search when looking for the minimum :)

Comment: I suppose there is still no strictly standards-blessed container for this if I am frequently finding myself trying to get the max/min values of a map?

Comment: @Dilip: No, there is not. The Standard only provides the most common structures; and none support double-indexing. Boost.MultiIndex and Boost.Bimap are fairly stable (for years), or you have to do you it yourself.