# Pick out the least recurring number in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I need help picking out the least recurring element in an array. I can't think of any robust algorithm, is there any function defined in the c++ library that does that?

If there is an algorithm that you can come up with, please share. Not the code necessarily, but the idea

**'Define least recurring'** - suppose an array say `a[4]` holds `2,2,2,4`. `4` is the least recurring element

Comment: define least recurrent element? if you meant the element appears the least, simply use a hash table

Comment: `std::sort` the array, then iterate over the array ?

Comment: suppose an array say a[4] holds 2,2,2,4. 4 is the least recurring element.

Comment: Jarod, yup, that's something I didn't think of, but I need to pick out the number. How would I do that?

Comment: You should make this considerably clearer by saying whether the item *type* requires strict weak ordering support. Obviously `int` supports this but some arbitrary type `T` may not. I.e. for some `T a,b`, then `a==b` (and inversely `a!=b`) may make sense, but `T` may not support strict weak ordering, and as such `a < b` may not make sense. It is important because strict weak ordering is *not* required to solve your problem, but *is* required for any answer that employs `std::sort`. And again, if there is more than one least-recurring element with the same frequency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uses some C++14 features for brevity but easily adapted to C++11:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

template <typename I>
auto leastRecurring(I first, I last) {
    unordered_map<iterator_traits<I>::value_type, size_t> counts;
    for_each(first, last, [&counts](auto e) { ++counts[e]; });
    return min_element(begin(counts), end(counts), [](auto x, auto y) { return x.second < y.second; })->first;
}

int main() {
    const int a[] = {2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4};
    cout << leastRecurring(begin(a), end(a)) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using only `std` goodies ([live demo on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4a1015813f32195)):

```
// Your original vector
auto original = { 2, 2, 2, 4, 4 };

// Sort numbers and remove duplicates (in a copy, because std::unique modifies the contents)
std::vector<int> uniques(original);
std::sort(std::begin(uniques), std::end(uniques));
auto end = std::unique(std::begin(uniques), std::end(uniques));

// Count occurences of each number in the original vector
// The key is the number of occurences of a number, the value is the number
std::map<int, int> population;

for (auto i = uniques.begin(); i != end; ++i) {
    population.emplace(std::count(std::begin(original), std::end(original), *i), *i);
}

// The map is sorted by key, therefore the first element is the least recurring
std::cout << population.begin()->second;
```

Note that in the example you gave, the array is already sorted. If you know that this will always be the case, you can get rid of the call to `std::sort`.

If two numbers have the same population count, the greater one will be kept.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

def leastFrequentToken(tokens):
    counted = Counter(tokens)
    leastFrequent = min(counted, key=counted.get)
    return leastFrequent
```

Essentially, create a map of token:count, find the smallest value in the map and return its key.

Assuming the 'numbers' are ints:

```
// functor to compare k,v pair on value
typedef std::pair<int, size_t> MyPairType;
struct CompareSecond
{
    bool operator()(const MyPairType& left, const MyPairType& right) const
    {
        return left.second < right.second;
    }
};


vector<int> tokens[4] = { 2, 2, 2, 4 };
map<int, size_t> counted;

for (vector<int>::iterator i=tokens.begin(); i!=tokens.end(); ++i)
{
    ++counted[*i];
}

MyPairType min 
      = *min_element(counted.begin(), counted.end(), CompareSecond());

int leastFrequentValue = min.second;
```

C++ translation using these SO question answers:
[C++ counting instances / histogram using std::map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8010761/c-counting-instances-histogram-using-stdmap),
[Finding minimum value in a Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659248/finding-minimum-value-in-a-map)

Comment: That's some awfully pythonic-looking C++ you've got there!

Comment: @Emmet: Yeah, Python is much the easiest way to explain the concept. I've added the C++ version as well, though there is likely to be a cleaner way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

in C++11, assuming your type support strict weak ordering (for `std::sort`), following may help: https://ideone.com/poxRxV

```
template <typename IT>
IT least_freq_elem(IT begin, IT end)
{
    std::sort(begin, end);
    IT next = std::find_if(begin, end, [begin](decltype(*begin) el) { return el != *begin; });
    IT best_it = begin;
    std::size_t best_count = next - begin;
    for (IT it = next; it != end; it = next) {
        next = std::find_if(it, end, [it](decltype(*begin) el) { return el != *it; });
        const std::size_t count = next - it;
        if (count < best_count) {
            best_count = count;
            best_it = it;
        }
    }
    return best_it;
}
```