# vector referencing C++

Tags: c++, vector, reference

Not sure if I’ve posted the right question for what I’m actually asking but here it is. I am trying to print the maximum and minimum rainfall from the `sumofrain` vector along with the corresponding year from the `yearly` vector.

Just to make it clear if the maximum rainfall in the `sumofrain` vector was the 7th value in the vector then the year I would like being output is the 7th value in the `yearly` vector ect.

Comment: What's your actual question?

Comment: How can i print the maximum and minimum value of the 'sumofrain' (which i've already done) with the corresponding year in the 'yearly' vector. For example if  the maximum value being output is 7th in the 'sumofrain' vector then how can i also output the 7th value in the 'yearly' vector. @TheForestAndTheTrees

Comment: @IrrationalPerson It is in the question.

Comment: You don't need a full sort to do what you need, there's a much simpler way to do it.

Comment: Simplest way to do this would be to create a class to read everything into, instead of having everything in separate vectors.

Comment: @TheForestAndTheTrees a full blown class might be overkill for this, a `std::vector` of `std::pairs` could be sufficient, or an `std::map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the vectors `yearly` and `sumofrain` are *not* jagged, you can simply check the distance from the beginning.

```
// Get iterator to the max element in container.
auto it = std::max_element(std::begin(sumofrain), std::end(sumofrain));

// Get index of element pointed to by iterator.
auto index = std::distance(std::begin(sumofrain), it);

auto maxRain = *it;
auto maxYear = yearly[index];

std::cout << "Wettest year: " << maxYear << ". ";
std::cout << "Rainfall recorded: " << maxRain << " mm." << std:: endl;
```

Comment: when using cout to display this what variable would i use? and thank you for your help. @snps

Comment: @louiej15 Both `maxRain` and `maxYear` have type `double` (value type of the containers), and you can output these using `std::cout` and  `<<` operator.

Comment: This brings the error, 'it,index,maxYear,maxRain' does not name a type

Comment: What compiler are you using? Possibly it's not c++11 compliant, required for (that usage of) the auto keyword.

Comment: @louiej15 The modern use of the `auto` keyword for type deduction is introduced in C++11, the second most recent standard (current is C++14). If you are using an old compiler that does not support the more recent standards you might get these errors.

Answer (score 0):

Store the sum-of-rain in a map of year -> double.

```
std::map<int, double>  rainfall;
while(file >> year >> month >> maxdeg >> mindeg >> afdays >> rainmm >> sunhours) 
  {
    rainfall[year] += rainmm;
    frost.push_back(afdays);
  }
```

Then, when the file is done reading, find the entry in the map with the lowest/highest rainfall, via e.g. [Finding minimum value in a Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659248/finding-minimum-value-in-a-map)

The iterator you get back has `->first` which is the year and `->second` which is the actual amount of rainfall for that year.

Answer (score 0):

You should store the iterator returned by `max_element(sumofrain.begin(),sumofrain.end())` into a variable.

```
auto itMax = max_element(sumofrain.begin(),sumofrain.end());
```

Then, to find out the zero-based index of the found element:

```
itMax - sumofrain.begin();
```

And to find the value :

```
*itMax
```