# How to find minimum value in std::map<std::string, float>?

Tags: c++, algorithm, comparator, stdmap, minimum

I am trying to get the minimum value in a `std::map`. I have a function which is from [Finding minimum value in a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659248/finding-minimum-value-in-a-map)

```
#import tool.mm
std::map<std::string, float> direction;
std::pair<std::string, float> min;

direction["up"] = 50.0;
direction["down"] = 20.0;
direction["right"] = 100.0;
direction["left"] = 200.0;

min = *min_element(direction.begin(), direction.end(), &Tool::compare);
```

This is what `Tool` class looks like:

```
//tool.mm
class Tool 
{
public:
    bool compare(std::pair<std::string, float> i, std::pair<std::string, float> j) {
        return (i.second < j.second);
    }
};
```

When I run this function I get an error showing

```
Called object type 'bool (Tool::*)(std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char>, float>, std::__1::pair<std::__1::basic_string<char>, float>)' is not a function or function pointer
```

Comment: If you're using C++ 11 or above, just use a lambda instead of a member function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *compare function* what you provided is not a *[functor](https://www.quantstart.com/articles/Function-Objects-Functors-in-C-Part-1)*.

It supposed to be

```
using Pair = std::pair<const std::string, float>; // just a alias type for convenience
struct Tool
{
    bool operator()(const Pair& i, const Pair& j)const 
        /*^^^^^^^^*/                            /*^^^*/
    {
        return (i.second < j.second);
    }
};
```

and you should be calling it like

```
min = *min_element(direction.begin(), direction.end(), Tool());
                                                       ^^^^^^
```

---

However, if you have access to C++11 or later versions, just use lambda which will help you to see the definition of compare function(binary predicate) on the line where you call.

```
min = *min_element(direction.begin(), direction.end(), 
                   [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs){ return lhs.second < rhs.second;});
```